# What diagram is used to represent a protocol between multiple system?

Tags: .net, uml

Multiple system are using COM object to communicate and is implemented by using interfaces.

I need to represent these interfaces in a diagram. Any known (UML)diagram to represent this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, UML's **Component diagram** is very convenient to represent **required** and **implemented** interfaces of some specific component of your system. **Component** is defined to be an *autonomous, encapsulated units within system that provide certain number of interfaces (and require some of them as well)*. As you are dealing with COM objects, these can be very conveniently modelled as *Components* of Component diagram with implemented and required interfaces.

Btw, I'm talking about the Component diagram of UML 2.0 (in the previous version of UML language, this diagram and components had different meaning that wouldn't suit your needs).

[More on UML Component diagram](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/)

Comment: In addition, one can document a protocol between interfaces as a protocol state machine or sequence diagram. (How to diagram the protocol was the title question.)

Answer (score 0):

To describe a protocol you will need static and dynamic description. The static one can be realized via class diagrams. Additionally you may show the usage of protocols in component diagrams. The dynamic part can be show via any communication or sequence diagram.

Comment: I dont have any knowledge on the other systems Classes, and therefore can not make a class diagram for the static description.

Comment: Well, a protocol needs an interface and that is a stereotyped class. So you can put that in a class diagram to show the methods.